# `shell-command` output not working when in a function

Tags: shell-command

I have

```
(shell-command-to-string "ls")
```

which works just fine but when I put it in a function it breaks as

```
(defun testing ()
  (shell-command-to-string "ls")
)
```

outputs `nil`. I am new to `elisp` so I am clearly missing something. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  How are you calling the function `testing`?

Comment: Just `testing()` and running `C-x C-e` on the function itself then the calling of the function.

Comment: To call the function, you have to write `(testing)` - if you do `C-x C-e` after that, does it work?

Comment: @NickD Thanks for that! Everything seems to work now. Want to make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You should probably add the way that you tried to call the function to your question. Without that detail, the question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lisp, a function call is denoted like this: `(func arg1 arg2 ...)`. IOW, the first element of the list is the function and subsequent elements are the (evaluated) arguments. Contrast this with most other languages where a function call is denoted like this: `func(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

So you *define* the function like this:

```el
(defun testing ()
  (shell-command-to-string "ls")
)
```

Doing `C-x C-e` after the closing paren evaluates the `defun` and adds the definition of the function to the system. Then to *call* the function you say:

```el
(testing)
```

This *calls* the function `testing` with *no* arguments.

You should probably read the "Introduction to Programming in Elisp" which can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html).